# Symbols in .lib are not there in .so

Tags: c, linux, linker, symbols

I have a library file (.lib) where there are many functions. I am trying to build a shared object out of it. But non of the symbols in library are there in shared object that are in library. However, when I generate executable out of the same library the symbols are visible.

Is some thing wrong with libraries?
Do I need to compile libraries in a format suitable for creating shared object?

Comment: What exactly is that .lib file? An archive or shared library or something else? Post how you compiled it and how you are building your shared library and executable.

Comment: There are a bunch of make files i have been given. I am using those to build .lib(archives). can you suggest how to make an .so out of it?

Answer (score 3):

What linkers do is they pull only those `.o` files from an archive `.a` that resolve an unresolved symbol.

When you link a shared library and pass only `.a` files to the linker, there are no unresolved symbols, hence no object files from `.a` get pulled into the shared library.

To link a shared library the object files must be compiled as position independent code (`-fPIC`, `.o` files for `.a` are normally built without this option) and then linked into a shared library. No `.a` files are necessary for that.

Another option is when linking `.a` files is to explicitly undefine the symbols that are present in `.a` using `-Wl,--undefined=<symbol>` linker option. But this does not scale well because it requires mentioning at least one symbol from each `.o` comprising `.a` (assuming the linker pulls in an entire `.o`, rather than just one symbol from it).